# Moved labels in QGIS 1.8 disappear on saving vector file

Tags: qgis, labeling

From other posts I worked out how to activate the "move label" icon and was successfully able to move a number of labels into the positions I wanted. However when I untoggle the "edit" function for the vector file concerned the labels that I have just moved all disappear - leaving me with only the unmoved labels.

I cannot find anyway to bring them back. How do I stop the moved labels from disappearing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coordinates of moved labels are stored in the attribute table. It could be that the coordinates are truncated when they are permanently saved. Check before and after toggling "edit" to see if this is the cause.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's happening. I'm a bit new to all of this - and in adding the dummy X and Y fields to the vector file I set it ti "text string" and length of 4 (thinking this would cover the words "NULL"). Now I see how it works. So it seems OK now that I've redone it and set a length of 10.

However i'm also wondering if I should've set it to decimal rather than text?

Comment: I'd definitely recommend decimal. (Please accept the answer if your problem is solved.)